# Oracle Metadata - How can I get table create date?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, database-administration

Is there any Oracle metadata table that show me the created date from a specific table?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select object_name, created
from user_objects
where object_type = 'TABLE'
  and object_name = '...'
```

You can user `all_objects` or `dba_objects` instead of `user_objects`, depending on your privileges and on the users you are interested in